# SOLR: Filter query (fq) with multiple fields (a tuple of fields)

Tags: solr

How can I have a filter query for a tuple of fields?

Here's an example. Let's say I have documents that contain `distance` and `id` fields. Example data:

```
distance | id
-------------
10.0     |  5
10.0     |  6
10.0     |  7
11.0     |  8
13.0     |  9
```

Now I would like to get items that match the following condition `(distance, id) > (10.0, 6)`. So the response should be like this:

```
10.0     |  7
11.0     |  8
13.0     |  9
```

How can I do this in SOLR?

I know that it's something similar to cursors, but I would like to be able to fetch data starting from any document.

Comment: The requirement would be that there will always be a unique key field in the sort order (this is the same limitation that Solr has for its cursorMark - _sort clauses must include the uniqueKey field (either asc or desc)._) - if `id` matches that condition and you're sorting by it, you could use an inclusive range for the fields before the uniqueKey and exclusive for the uniqueKey-part, I'd think? `fq=distance:[10.0 TO *] AND id:{6 TO *]`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
The condition `(distance, id) > (10.0, 6)` is equivalent to `distance > 10.0 OR (distance = 10.0 AND id>6)`. So we generally search for distance greater than 10.0, but in case it's equal to 10.0, then we search for id>6.

And this translated to a filter query looks like this:

```
fq=distance:{10.0 TO *] OR (distance:10.0 AND id:{6 TO *])
```

A caveat is that if the distance is computed using a function, then you have to use `frange` and put it in parentheses. Example:

```
mygeodist=geodist()&fq=({!frange l=10.0 incl=false}$mygeodist) OR (({!frange l=10.0 u=10.0}$mygeodist) AND id:{6 TO *])
```